# Services or intent services to send location updates every 5 sec to server endlessly?

Tags: android, service, geolocation, android-volley, android-intentservice

I am using `GoogleCientApi` object to fetch location updates and other `Accelerometer` sensors and send it to server every 5 sec . I want it to run in background endlessly i.e. 24*7 with battery optimisation. Nothing needs to be updated in `UI`. Please suggest whether to use `Service` or `IntentService`?
If using `Service` how to run it using `Handler`? Any suggestion or article link will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this using service

```
    public class MyService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        // This schedule a runnable task every x unit of time
        scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                callAPI();
            }
        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void callAPI() 
    {
    //Upload data to server and do your stuff
    }
}
```

Also you need to register your service in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service
        android:name=".service.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

And call your service through Activity

```
if (!checkServiceRunning()) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is posible with use of following component

Use **Android Foreground Service** for get current location while app open / close.

> Note: Latest Android versions is not allowing to get current location
>   through Backghround service.

Use **Socket/Pusher** for update location to user server.

**Reference link**

1). https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

2). http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/

For Socket

1). https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

2). https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

For Pusher

1). https://pusher.com/docs/android_quick_start